# swing.JFrame closes immediately

Tags: java, swing, jframe

im' new to JFrame and here’s a strange problem: after a split second, the window immediately closes. I tried to run from the command line(compiles without errors) and in Intellij IDEA (in Intellij Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)), the window in both cases opens for a split second

windows 10 pro 64 java version - openjdk 13.0.2 javac 13.0.2 jre-8u241

I will be glad to any information:)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FractalExplorer extends JFrame {
    static final int WIDTH = 600;
    static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    public FractalExplorer(){
        setInitialGUIProperties();
    }

    public void setInitialGUIProperties(){
        this.setTitle("Fractal Explorer");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FractalExplorer();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to comment out or remove the setLocationRekativeTo riw

Comment: `this.setVisible(true)` should be the last statement of your `setInitialGUIProperties()` method

Comment: You should launch your frame on the Event Dispatch Thread. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to do that. No idea if that'll solve your problem though.

Comment: While there are a number of questionable aspects to the code seen above, I cannot reproduce the stated problem here (the frame stays visible until closed by me).

Comment: Why is your JDK version 13 when your JRE version is 8?